# Marketing Cloud - Mobile Connect Campaign Codes and Tags

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, campaign

In Mobile Connect you can create a Campaign to associate with your SMS messages. Can someone explain to me the purpose of the 'Campaign Code' and 'Tag' option. Surely if it's for reporting then the Campaign association alone would suffice?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Campaign Code is used to uniquely identify a campaign.
For example, for credit card campaigns you can start with CC0001 and then increment by 1 or 2 for future campaigns. It can be used to identify the campaign in reporting.

Tags can be created for types of campaigns:
For example:
1. Daily
2. Weekly
3. Monthly etc..

Tags can be added to the campaign for organization and tracking